# Make batch file interpret instructions line-by-line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

**-WHAT I NEED**

How can I create a batch file that interprets external instructions (not batch code) and puts them in a variable?

---

**-WHAT I GOT**

A sourceforge project called "Easy-Series" (For easier debunking, [here](https://www.mediafire.com/?um876x92cw1b6eh) is the download link for every dependency as well as main file; Ignore crashing when you put external commands, will fix that later, but if you can fix it, Please mention it in the comments.)

---

**-SOLUTIONS THAT I HAVE RULED OUT**

`set`
doesnt seem to work because I think it only grabs the first line of a file encoded in plain text format... Am I right? If not then you can theorize a solution...

**-EXAMPLES EXPLAINED THOROUGHLY**

Say I have a text file named `commands.txt`. I have a few **EXTERNAL** commands there to be **INTERPRETED** by an interpreter, of which I will code. I only need the "reading each line and put each line in separate variable" part. ***ONCE AGAIN***, these commands are **NOT** batch commands, ***THESE ARE EXTERNAL COMMANDS*** which I need to be interpreted by an interpreter;

```
newfolder test
newfile test.txt
ping google.com
```

since I've already told you that this "Command Interpreter" called `easycommandengine` (Which aims for easier use of windows command line) interprets external instructions, I want each line to be put in a seperate variable

```
line 1 = ecl_ecmdengine_line%linecount%
line 2 = ecl_ecmdengine_line%linecount%
line 3 = ecl_ecmdengine_line%linecount%
line 4 = ecl_ecmdengine_line%linecount%
and so on and so forth
```

**WHAT I MEAN BY THIS is THAT**, say, **LINE 1** of `commands.txt` which is `newfolder test` to be saved in variable "ecl_ecmdengine_line1"... 1 would be the `%linecount%` variable.

If you STILL don't understand (tl;dr?): I technically mean that I want a batch file to read .txt files with instructions the same way `cmd` reads batch files...

I'd also like the code to make %linecount% variable (which I suppose is already self-explanatory) work... I'm too newby to make `for` commands which just makes my mind blow up...

---

**-NOTES**

Once again, [HERE](https://www.mediafire.com/?um876x92cw1b6eh) are the files if you want to test my code out on your computer yourself...

If you think I have given *too much* or *too few* information, PM or Comment on this post, and I will try and fix it as soon as I can.

Comment: Please give examples.  Your question isn't very clear as it stands.

Comment: @foxidrive Done... please read again. I need an answer quick

Comment: The examples don't make anything clearer for me.

Answer (score 0):

Test this - the last command will list the variables:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("commands.txt") do (
set /a c+=1
set "command[!c!]=%%a"
)
set command[
```

Comment: Works... so.. my mind technically thinking too hard that I forgot on how to pass these variables and execute them.. god damn it stupid me.... I need more help D:

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "numLines=0"
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "commands.txt"') do (
        set "ecl_ecmdengine_line%%a=%%b"
        set /a "numLines+=1"
    )

    for /l %%a in (1 1 %numLines%) do (
        call echo line %%a is :%%ecl_ecmdengine_line%%a%%
    )

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /l %%a in (1 1 %numLines%) do (
        echo line %%a is :!ecl_ecmdengine_line%%a!
    )
    endlocal
```

How to read lines from file (`findstr` is used to numerate the lines), and how to access its contents with or without delayed expansion enabled.

Comment: Works very nicely, can't decide which code to pick, foxidrive's or yours.

Comment: @EpicTonic, The two works. Select the code that you better understand or that better fits with the rest of your project. You will have to maintain it.

Comment: i feel yours work fits with the code, since it works very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers from foxidrive and MC ND would solve your immediate problem, that is load lines from `commands.txt` into an [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) named `ecl_ecmdengine_line`. However, after that you need to process each one of the lines stored in the array, that is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load lines from commands.txt into ecl_ecmdengine_line array:
set numLines=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (commands.txt) do (
   set /A numLines+=1
   set "ecl_ecmdengine_line!numLines!=%%a"
)

rem Process the lines in ecl_ecmdengine_line array:
for /L %%i in (1,1,%numLines%) do echo process line %%i: !ecl_ecmdengine_line%%i!
```

However, previous method seems a waste to me. You may read the lines from `commands.txt` file and directly process them with no necessity to store they in any array. The Batch code below is an example of this method that also show how the commands could be processed:

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in (commands.txt) do call %%a %%b
goto :EOF

:newfolder
echo Creating newfolder for %*
exit /B

:newfile
echo Creating newfile for %*
exit /B

:ping
echo Executing ping with %*
exit /B
```

Comment: Good explanation... i will try that out later since i'm on my tab.